# LibGDX: shadow is not showing

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

To demonstrate my problem I use libgdx's [ShadowMappingTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShadowMappingTest.java).

This test has model with box and sphere:

```
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.begin();
        MeshPartBuilder mpb = modelBuilder.part("parts", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.ColorUnpacked,
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
        mpb.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        mpb.box(0, -1.5f, 0, 10, 1, 10);
        mpb.setColor(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
        mpb.sphere(2f, 2f, 2f, 10, 10);
        model = modelBuilder.end();
        instance = new ModelInstance(model);
```

And on screen: 
[image]

Then I replaced sphere by triangle:

```
        val modelBuilder = ModelBuilder()
        modelBuilder.begin()
        val mpb = modelBuilder.part("parts",
                                    GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                                    (Usage.Position or Usage.Normal or Usage.ColorUnpacked).toLong(),
                                    Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)))
        mpb.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
        mpb.box(0f, -1.5f, 0f, 10f, 1f, 10f)
        mpb.setColor(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f)

        mpb.triangle(Vector3(0f, 2f, 3f),     <<<<<< look
                     Vector3(3f, 2f, 0f),
                     Vector3(0f, 2f, 0f))

        model = modelBuilder.end()
        instance = ModelInstance(model)
```

And I got:
[image: img]

Where is shadow of the triangle?
How can I fix it?

Comment: I think that triangles can't have shadows because they are not 3D objects.